# Estrutura de dados para comparar permissão de acesso entre objetos (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Consigo autenticar mas, a permissão na funciona corretamente com a roleMatch

//Saída no console

userRoles:  [{…}]
0: {roleNome: 'Usuario', roleDescricao: 'Função padrão para registro recém-criado'}

allowedRoles:  ['Admin']
0: "Admin"

userRoles:  [{…}]
0: {roleNome: 'Usuario', roleDescricao: 'Função padrão para registro recém-criado'}

allowedRoles: ['Usuario']
0: "Usuario"

//Html
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iThmP.png)

Painel Admin
        
        
          Painel Usuario

//Uso indexOf() retorna o primeiro índice em que o elemento pode ser encontrado no array, retorna -1 caso o mesmo não esteja presente.

public roleMatch(allowedRoles: any): boolean {

```
let isMatch = false;
const userRoles: any = this.userAuthService.getRoles();

if(userRoles != null && userRoles) {
  for(let i=0; i < userRoles.length; i++) {
    console.log('userRoles: ',userRoles);
    for(let j=0; j < allowedRoles.length; j++) {
    
      //if(userRoles[i].roleName === allowedRoles[j]){}// não funciona
      console.log('allowedRoles: ',allowedRoles);
      
      if(allowedRoles.indexOf(userRoles[i].roleName)){
        console.log('roleMatch achou: ',allowedRoles.indexOf(userRoles[i].roleName));
        isMatch = true;
        return isMatch;
      }
      else {
        console.log('roleMatch não achou: ',allowedRoles.indexOf(userRoles[i].roleName));
        return isMatch;
      }

    }
  }
}
return isMatch;
```

}

Comment: //Html
<li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" routerLink="/admin"
          *ngIf="userService.roleMatch(['Admin'])"
          >Painel Admin</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" routerLink="/usuario"
          *ngIf="userService.roleMatch(['Usuario'])"
          >Painel Usuario</a>
        </li>